# Grunt serve:dist (or build:dist) is creating broken css but no errors

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I am using Grunt as part of an angular fullstack app (along with yeoman and bower). All is good in development land, but running a distribution results in horribly corrupt css (see image)(in development this all runs fine - in dist, the markup is littered with icon tags).

I have found a number of posts that seem to suggest that fonts aren't being included etc, but in my case, my dist folder seems to have everything. Also, I am not getting ANY errors OR warnings, making debugging it more than tricky. Has anyone seen this before? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly an issue with glyphicons, most likely glyphicons not being packaged correctly, though I can't see why the dist target is an issue. Switching to use font-awesome has solved this for me,